# Meaning of void in detail

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java.I want to know the exact meaning of void and why do we use it? I referred  to many websites but it is not clear to me.

Also I wish to know why do we use void for method and not for constructor? 
Please help.

Comment: Void means nothing at all literally. There's no detail to it. And perhaps not just java, if you're beginner. Its a common norm in programming.

Comment: At the byte code level, constructors have the same signature as a method which returns `void`, you just don't specify it in code or it would be a method.

Comment: Sometimes we assume something much be more complicated that at first it appears. If `void` doesn't appear super simple you are over thinking it.

Answer (score 1):

The void keyword denotes that a method does not have a return type. When method return nothing then we declare method as void type.

Foe example :

```
public void voidMethod()   {    
  System.out.println("Method which return nothing"); 
}
```

> However, even though a constructor method can never have a return
>   type, it does not have the void keyword in its declaration.

For example :

```
public class Sample {    
   public Sample ()   {   
     System.out.println("Constructor");
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`void` is a return type in java which means, that it does not return any value.

Constructors do not have any return value, that's why `void` or any other return type is not used in constructor declaration.

From the [Java Documentation:](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

A class contains constructors that are invoked to create objects from the class blueprint. Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type.